# Dynamic Sticky Footer Height with Ryan Fait's Code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok there are a fair number of questions about [Ryan Fait's sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/), BUT please don't disregard this question immediately! What I am trying to do is have a dynamically sized height for my footer and have it stick to the bottom of the page.

Ryan Fait's solution is to wrap all the page content in `#wrapper` and set `#wrapper`'s `margin-bottom` to the height of the footer. This works very well when hardcoded into the CSS, but I don't know how large my footer is going to be. Because of this, I want to be able to set `#wrapper`'s `margin-bottom` with javascript. So far, I have been unsuccessful. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/6z6Uk/313/) is my setup.

I have been at this so long, I have very little hair to pull out. Do you see where my mistake is?

**The Code on JSFiddle**

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
   Wrapper
    </div> <!-- #wrapper -->

    <footer>
        Footer
    </footer>
</body>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    }
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    }
#wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto; /* Negative margin set with JS */
    }
footer {
    height: 100px;
    }
```

JQuery

```
$(window).load(function() {
    set_window_bottom_margin();
});

function set_window_bottom_margin() {
    var margin = $('footer').outerHeight(true);

    $('.wrapper').css('margin-bottom', margin * -1 + 'px');
}
```

Comment: Can you add the markup/css and script to your question as well in case jsfiddle goes black?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do this in css nowdays:

```
html, body {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
}
body {
  display:table;
}
main, footer {
  display:table-row;
}
main {height:100%;background:red;}
footer {background:green;}
footer:hover br {display:none;}/* whatever else on footer:hover s for demo purpose */
```

```
<main>
  <div>
    main
  </div>
</main>
<footer>
  <div>
    footer<br/>
    footer<br/>
  </div>
</footer>
```

DEMO http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EvHwk